# Preallocate storage with fcntl doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, macos, filesystems, darwin, fcntl

I want to preallocate storage with the system call `fcntl`. Here is my code to do so:

```
fstore_t store = {F_ALLOCATECONTIG, F_PEOFPOSMODE, 0, length, 0};
int ret = fcntl(fd, F_PREALLOCATE, &store);
if (ret == -1) {
    store.fst_flags = F_ALLOCATEALL;
    ret = fcntl(fd, F_PREALLOCATE, &store);
}
```

The variable `ret` is not `-1` after executing that code. When I get the file size by calling `fstat` on the same file handle, I get `stat.st_size = 0`. But the value `store.fst_bytesalloc` equals the value of `length`.
What do I have to do? When I call

```
ftruncate(fd, length);
```

do I get a file with a hole or is it a 'real' file without holes? The second one is my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is a contiguous space **only** you should should call `fcntl` with `F_ALLOCATECONTIG` flag and fail if `ret == -1`.

The second call to `fcntl` in your code (without `F_ALLOCATECONTIG` flag set) will try to preallocate non-contiguous space (as contiguous allocation failed).

`ftruncate` call is needed on darwin to have file size reported correctly. Without the call space is being reserved, but file size reported is still zero. Read this [article](https://blog.mozilla.org/tglek/2010/09/09/help-wanted-does-fcntlf_preallocate-work-as-advertised-on-osx/) that states that:

> It appears that the posix_fallocate equivalent [on OS X] is to the fnctl
>   followed by a truncate() call (which actually forces data to be
>   written to the file)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does this code work as expected with every file system, e.g. ext4 where sparse files are supported? So do I get on those file systems also a file without holes?

Comment: This should work with OS X native file systems. Non-native file systems support probably depends on third party tools, like fuse for ext4.

Comment: From the [fcntl man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/fcntl.2.html),  `F_ALLOCATECONTIG ` is not a cmd for `fcntl`.

Comment: @Karl The man page says: "The flags (fst_flags) for the `F_PREALLOCATE` command are as follows: `F_ALLOCATECONTIG`   Allocate contiguous space. ..."